# Python, splitting strings

Tags: python, string, split

I have a large string text file, I would like to split the string every 117 characters and put the next 117 chars on a newline, and so on until the end of the file.

I tried this:`s = """
I have removed the string for visibility reasons
"""
space = """

"""
file = open('testoutput.txt', 'w')
while s:
    print s[:10]
    output = output + s + """

```
"""
s = s[10:]
```

file.write(output)
file.close()
print "Done"
`

but had the issue where the final output in the file looked like this cascading:`    this [SHIFT]r[BACKSPACE]molecule and its descendants would av[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]vary because of mutations

```
T]r[BACKSPACE]molecule and its descendants would av[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]vary because of mutations



ACE]molecule and its descendants would av[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]vary because of mutations



le and its descendants would av[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]vary because of mutations



 descendants would av[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]vary because of mutations



ts would av[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]vary because of mutations



v[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]vary because of mutations



E][BACKSPACE]vary because of mutations



CE]vary because of mutations



cause of mutations



utations
```

`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while s:
    print s[:117]
    s = s[117:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either split a buffer using the regular slicing syntax, or you may opt to split the file directly while reading it. This is an example of the second approach:

```
with open(r"/path/to/some/file") as input_file:
    line = input_file.read(117)
    while line:
        print len(line)
        line = input_file.read(117)
```